# How to sort string as numbers in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I have string column with specific numbers in a datagridview. It's not bound. I would like to sort it correctly. Default DataGridView sorting doesn't sort it correct.

Example: 
Dgv sorts it like this:

```
 - FS 752/08/2014
 - FS 752/06/2015
 - FS 751/12/2013
 - FS 751/08/2014
 - FS 751/06/2015
```

And it should be like this:

```
 - FS 752/06/2015
 - FS 751/06/2015
 - FS 752/08/2014
 - FS 751/08/2014
 - FS 751/12/2013
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: try make a special `Comparer` and use `DataGridView.Sort` method with that comparer. Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have stated you are not using a `DataSource` then you could try using the [`SortCompare` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare(v=vs.110).aspx).

This event will be called when the user clicks a column to change the sort order, or when you programatically call the [`Sort` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is a basic example. I am making assumptions that you want to sort be year(?) then month(?) then the first number:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{

    // Check if we are sorting by the special column.
    if (myDataGridView.Columns.Contains("My_Column") && e.Column == myDataGridView.Columns["My_Column"])
    {

        // Parse the special values (add validation if required).
        string[] parts1 = e.CellValue1.ToString().Trim().Split('/');
        int a1 = int.Parse(parts1[0].Split(' ')[2]);
        int b1 = int.Parse(parts1[1]);
        int c1 = int.Parse(parts1[2]);
        string[] parts2 = e.CellValue2.ToString().Trim().Split('/');
        int a2 = int.Parse(parts2[0].Split(' ')[2]);
        int b2 = int.Parse(parts2[1]);
        int c2 = int.Parse(parts2[2]);

        // Compare each value as required.

        // First compare the last value (year?)
        e.SortResult = c1.CompareTo(c2);

        // If equal, then compare second value (month?)
        if(e.SortResult == 0)
            e.SortResult = b1.CompareTo(b2);

        // Finally if still equal, then compare first value
        if(e.SortResult == 0)
            e.SortResult = a1.CompareTo(a2);

    }

}
```

**NOTE**: If you cannot ensure you will always have a valid format in every cell, then you will need to add validation logic to this event. For example, use `int.TryParse()` and check for `null` values, and validate the length of the `string` splits.

Comment: Perfect! I've used this solution, just modify it a little and it sorts perfect! I'm very glad, thank you :)