# How to sort string as numbers in DataGridView with DataSouce binded

Tags: c#, vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datatable

According to my [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336046/how-to-sort-string-as-numbers-in-datagridview) I've changed the data source for datagridview. Now it is bound from DataTable. In this situation `SortCompare` event doesn't even fire. How can I call my event `SortCompare` now? It was sorting perfectly...

EDIT:
I don't need normal sorting like `"column_name DESC"`, so `dt.DefaultView.Sort` doesn't work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you Sort a DataTable given column and direction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005658/how-do-you-sort-a-datatable-given-column-and-direction)

Comment: You need to call the Sort() function. Did you do that?

Comment: Yeah I tried but it is not normal sorting. It is sorting by year then month then the first number. I need to use my sorting logic here. I need to use code which @musefan added on that my last question

Comment: Instead of 3 sortings, couldn't you just convert the string you have to a formatted date time and then compare times?

Comment: @Gnqz, unfortunatelly not, this string won't always be like date format

Comment: What are the possible contents of the string? If it's not datetime, then what is it? You could use a method that determines whenever the string contains datetime information and either sort it or branch accordingly. This shouldn't be much of a burden.

Comment: Sometimes string is just like `service1`, `service2`, etc. But for example: `FS 752/08/2014` is not a datetime format, because what is 752?